# "node"" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

Hola que tal? Me gustaria saber si alguien sabe como solucionar el siguiente error en atom :

> "node"" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
>   [Finished in 0.208s]

Instale el package "**script**", para poder ejecutar como consola, en lenguaje "**Javascript**", pero al ejecutarlo me da el error mencionado.
Probe ejecutar otros script en html, python, etc y se ejecutan sin problmas. Es con javascript que no me deja ejecutar. Ni mostrar un error en pantalla.

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

gracias desde ya.
saludos.

Comment: En mi caso se solucionó instalando Node.Js El error ocurría cuando intentaba ejecutar un trozo de código desde VS Code con la extensión Code Runner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algunos lenguajes tienen requisitos especiales. En el caso de JavaScript se requiere de Node.js y que `node` esté como variable del `PATH`.

Además, de acuerdo a https://atom.io/packages/script para evitar el error referido se indica que debe lanzarse Atom desde la consola/terminal. Adicionalmente debe asegurarse de ejecutarlo en la ruta de proyecto requerido.

### Cita textual

> **Atom can't find node | ruby | python | my socks**
>
> Make sure to launch Atom from the console/terminal. This gives atom
>   all your useful environment variables. Additionally, make sure to run
>   it with the project path you need. For example, use
>
> ```
> atom .
> ```
>
> to get it to run with the current directory as the default place to
>   run scripts from.
>
> If you really wish to open atom from a launcher/icon, see this issue
>   for a variety of workarounds that have been suggested.

Comment: no, me sigue dando el mismo error. Te agradezco la respuesta. no decia que requeria variable de entorno, y por ese motivo no habia puesto, ahora ingese una `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\atom\bin`, y `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem`.. por si era ese el problema.. pero no se ya..

Comment: @JohnRamirez : Actualicé mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Me ha pasado lo mismo y era porque no tenía esta ruta en el PATH.
Para ponerla debes entrar en el Panel de Control -> Sistema y Seguridad -> Sistema -> Ajustes Avanzado de Sistema -> entorno variable -> Path

Le das a nueva y pones esta ruta: C:\Program Files\nodejs, luego le das a subir hasta colocarla la primera.

Un saludo y espero haberte ayudado!